# Exp:resso Store passing credit card name

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

We were using the EWAY merchant plugin for Exp:resso Store and noticed that it was passing the incorrect credit card name to EWAY - instead it's reporting the billing_name for some reason, and not the name from the `<input name="payment[name]"/>` field.

I understand the store doesn't record any credit card info, but is there a setting I'm missing or something? Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `billing_name` is simply a fallback when no name is specified. Your card name input field should actually look like this:

```
<input name="payment[card_name]" />
```

I just looked at the example templates and realize this is incorrect, so will get that fixed up.

Also note there is now a dedicated [ExpressionEngine Q&A site](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/) which is a better place for questions like this :)

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, will hit up the new Q&A site for future questions.